# Woocommerce variation replacing period with a hyphen

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've a Woocommerce variation table. It shows each variation in table with respective info, it's working almost properly but I don't know why, it's replacing period with hyphen and even front slash with hyphen.

6.5 becomes 6-5. N/A becomes n-a. Image is attached be low

[image]

Here's my code

```html
    global $product, $post;
                $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                $gcounter = 1; ?>
<table>
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="model-class"><b>Model</b></th>
            <?php foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
                        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];

                        foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
                                $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $key );
                                $taxonomy_label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
                                $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name;
                                        ?>

            <th>
                <b><?php echo $taxonomy_label;?></b>
            </th>



            <?php

                        } ?>
            <th scope="col"><b>Price</b></th>
            <th scope="col" width="250"><b>Qty</b></th>
        </tr>

        <?php if ($gcounter == 1) {
                        break;
                    } ?>



        <?php  } ?>

    </thead>


    <?php

                foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
                ?>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="model-class">
                <?php $variation_sku = get_post_meta( $value['variation_id'] , '_sku', TRUE ); ?>

                <?php echo $variation_sku ;?>
            </td>
            <?php
                                if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                                    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                                        $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attr_key );
                                        $taxonomy_label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
                                        $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name;
                                    ?>
            <td class="<?php echo $taxonomy;?>">
                <b><?php echo $attr_value;?></b>
            </td>
            <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>


            <td class="price">
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                                        if ($value['price_html']){
                                            echo $value['price_html'];
                                        } else {
                                            echo '£'.number_format((float)$value['display_regular_price'], 2, '.', '');
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        echo 'Call/Enquire for prices';
                                    }

                                    ?>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity">
                <form id="addtocart" name="addtocart" class="variations_form cart"
                    action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post"
                    enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>"
                    data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $product->get_available_variations() ) ) ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id'];?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>">
                    <?php
                                        if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                                            foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                                                $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attr_key );
                                                $taxonomy_label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
                                                $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name;
                                            ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" data-attribute_name="<?php echo $attr_key?>"
                        name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value;?>">
                    <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                    <?php

                                    if ( $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                        $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                                    } else {
                                        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                            'input_name'   => "quantity",
                                            'max_value'    => $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                            'min_value'    => '1',
                                            'product_name' => $product->get_name(),
                                            'input_value' => '1',
                                        ), $product, false );
                                    }

                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.


                                    ?>
                </form>
                <div class="yith-ywraq-add-to-quote add-to-quote-addons-<?php echo $product_id ?>"
                    <?php echo $data_variations ?>>
                    <a href="#" class="add-request-quote-button button alt"
                        data-product_id="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>"
                        data-wp_nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(); ?>">Add to quote</a>
                </div>
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
                <button type="submit" onclick="document.addtocart.submit()" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"
                    form="addtocart"><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ), $product->product_type); ?></button><?php } ?>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <?php
            } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how it looks on backend
[image]

Comment: Because what you see is the product attributes **term slugs** on your table instead of the product attribute term names… Note that period (point) is not allowed on product attribute term slugs (and replaced by an hyphen), but it's allowed on the term name.

Comment: What are my options?

Comment: That is what I'm asking help regarding. How would I do that?